# Show that the $4$ points are concyclic

Tags: geometry, triangles

## Problem

Let$\triangle DEF,~ \triangle IJK $  be the pedal triangle and the  circumcevian triangle of $P$ with respect to $\triangle ABC$, $X,Y,Z$ be the points such that $D,E,F$ are the midpoints of $XI,YJ,ZK$, and $H$ be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC.$ Show that $X,Y,Z,H$ are concyclic.

[image]

## P.S

Indeed, the problem had been included in the book, **Geometry in Figures** by Arseniy Akopyan, which was numbered as 4.2.8). But it's a pity that there exists no proof all over the book.

I have tried so far but obtain nothing. Please give **a geometric proof** without much computation as far as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DEF
 is pedal triangle of which triangle??

Comment: the circumcevian triangle of $P$ with respect to $\triangle ABC.$

Comment: Statement is "Circle correspondence to circle about triangle" like mobius transform.